# Data archival from cosmos to ADLS

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, azure-data-factory

I am working on IOT data where I am getting data from every device every 1 second. This is coming through IOT hub then it is processed in Azure functions and finally stored in Cosmos DB. But this data is growing to massive scales so I want to set TTL in cosmos for 5 days and archive the data in ADLS that can be done periodically, either twice a day or once a day. But I am not able to figure out whether I should write a spark job to do this transfer or use any other robust and optimized approach? I want some suggestions on different approaches I can use for this use case.

Comment: why arent you using table storage? it's dirt cheap. cosmosdb is great if you are doing event sourcing, but it might be overkill for you

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data factory have a way to copy data from Cosmos DB to many data stores. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is using Data factory for everyday data archival not overkill? Is it cost effective approach?